# Python Program stopping in Between

Tags: python, image, urllib

I have written a python program to download a list of images using image urls. The image urls are stored in a file. The python program creates a list of urls from text file and downloads images. I am using urllib module to download image file and store it locally. I am printing the image downloaded url in the console.

The problem here is when started the program works fine and downloads images as per required, but suddenly the program pauses in between and does not download images further. It doesn't stop or throw any exception, it just pauses and i can see the last image downloaded on console. Than I have to restart the program to continue image download process.

Can anybody help me with this problem?
Below is the code that i have written:

```
import urllib
import hashlib
import os

f = open("/home/padmin/Image_Download/image_urls.txt")
to_download = f.readlines()
f.close()

downloaded = set()
try:
    f = open("Log.txt")
    downloaded = f.readlines()
    f.close()
except:
    print 'log opening error'
    pass

not_aval = open("/home/padmin/Image_Download/Image_Not_Available.txt",'a')
log_file= open("/home/padmin/Image_Download/Log.txt",'a')

to_download = set(to_download) - set(downloaded)

path = '/home/padmin/Image_Download/Images/'

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

for line in to_download:
    line = line.strip()
    print line
    h=hashlib.sha1(line).hexdigest()
    try:
        f = open(path+h+'.jpg','wb')
        f.write(urllib.urlopen(line).read())
        f.close()
        log_file.write(line+'\n')

    except Exception,e:
        print e
        try:
            not_aval.write(line+'\n')

        except Exception, e:
            print "exception: ",e

not_aval.close()
log_file.close()`
```

Comment: can it be because the server is limiting you ? however you should receive an exception

Comment: You can switch to `urllib2` and specify a timeout for the connection: `urllib.urlopen(url, timeout=1)`. Probably the server you're downloading images from is slow for some reason.

Comment: @XavierCombelle I had thought of that, but I am not receiving any exception.

Comment: @NigelTufnel I was using 2 seconds timeout earlier using time module of python. Still same problem, so removed it later .

Comment: The server could very well be throttling you by just leaving the connection open for a long time, rather than immediately sending an error response.